# How to search an array key by matching a string in it's value

Tags: php, arrays, find, string-matching

I'm trying to find the key number in a array matching a string.

I tried array_search in this way

```
$key = array_search("foo", $array);
echo $array[$key];
```

but that prints $array[0]

Is there another way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for a value that *exactly* matches your search string?  Or can your search string be a substring of the value you're looking for?  An example array to go with your search example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key is not found, `array_search` returns `false`. You have to check for that (line 3 in my example below)

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search("green", $array); //the $key will be "2"
if ($key !== false) {
   echo $array[$key];
}
```

Otherwise, your code seems to do what you need. If there is a problem, please, post more code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly matching the whole string, just one part, will array_search still work?

btw i made a loop through the array with for each that do a preg_match until it finds the string then breaks the loop and store the key in a array